# Get all rows on aggregate function in pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark and trying to get to display all row from the result of an aggregate function so as to use the columns in some other calculation.

I have 2 data-frames

**Quantity**

+----+-----+-----+----+

|ID| Size|

+---- +-----

| 1 |  3 |

| 1 |  3 |

| 1 | 3 |

| 2 |  6 |

| 2 | 6 |

+----+-----

**Price**
+----+-----+-----+----+

|ID| perf | Size|Date|

+---- +----- +----- +----+

| 1 | 7.5 | 3 |2017-01-03|

| 1 | 39 | 3 |2012-01-06|

| 1 | 12 | 3 |2009-04-01|

| 1 | 28 | 3 |2011-11-08|

| 1 | 9 | 3 |2012-09-12|

| 1 | 15 | 3 |2017-07-03|

| 1 | 10 | 3 |2017-05-03 |

| 1 | 33 | 3 |2012-03-08 |

| 2 | 53| 6 |2012-03-08 |

+----+-----+-----+----+

I have been able to perform a join on the 2 dataframes and also ordered by the date in order to get the start and end date for each ID.

This is what I have done

```
dJoin = quantity.join(price, (quantity.id==price.id) & (quantity.size==price.size)). select(quantity.id, quantity.size, price.perf, price.date)  

part_asc = Window.partitionBy(dJoin.id).orderBy((dJoin.date).desc())
part_desc = Window.partitionBy(dJoin.id).orderBy((dJoin.date).asc())  

add_cols = dJoin.withColumn("rnASC", row_number().over(part_asc)) \
                 .withColumn("rnDESC", row_number().over(part_desc))
```

The above code gives me the following:

+----+-----+-----+----+

|ID| perf | Size|Date| rnASC | rnDESC

+---- +----- +----- +----+-------+----

| 1 | 7.5 | 3 |2017-01-03|1|8

| 1 | 39 | 3 |2012-01-06|2|7

| 1 | 12 | 3 |2009-04-01|3|6

| 1 | 28 | 3 |2011-11-08|4|5

| 1 | 9 | 3 |2012-09-12|5|4

| 1 | 15 | 3 |2017-07-03|6|3

| 1 | 10 | 3 |2017-05-03 |7|2

| 1 | 33 | 3 |2012-03-08 |8|1

| 2 | 53| 6 |2012-03-08 |1|1

+----+-----+-----+----+

I am trying to get the **perf** column from when both the **rnASC** and **rnDESC** are 1 and then do a different of the two.

Currently I can show when both values are 1 but can't get access to the **perf**

```
add_cols.groupBy(add_cols.id).agg((min('rnASC')), min('rnDESC')).show()
```

The above only shows me the **ids** that are one but I think I need the corresponding **perf** that go with the **id** in order to do my differential calculation.

This for your help in advance!